# File downloaded always blank in Python, Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-views

I am using the following view in Django to create a file and make the browser download it

```
    def aux_pizarra(request):

        myfile = StringIO.StringIO()
        myfile.write("hello")       
        response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(myfile), content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=prueba.txt'
        return response
```

But the file downloaded is always blank.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to move the pointer to the beginning of the buffer with `seek` and use `flush` just in case the writing hasn't performed.

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
import StringIO

def aux_pizarra(request):

    myfile = StringIO.StringIO()
    myfile.write("hello")       
    myfile.flush()
    myfile.seek(0) # move the pointer to the beginning of the buffer
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(myfile), content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=prueba.txt'
    return response
```

This is what happens when you do it in a console:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> s.write('hello')
>>> s.readlines()
[]
>>> s.seek(0)
>>> s.readlines()
['hello']
```

There you can see how `seek` is necessary to bring the buffer pointer to the beginning for reading purposes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The file downloaded is still blank :S

Comment: I'll update the question with how it work within the interpreter.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work before. But I tried again and your solution works!. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Lol, I'm glad :) Maybe some browser cache issues or whatever! You're welcome :)