# Django HTTP Response not naming file correctly

Tags: python, django

I have a Django script that zips up files on a server and sends the zip file out when a query is sent to the server. However, the zip file keeps downloading with the name "download" instead of data.ZIP, data.ZIP is what is specify the name to be. Any ideas why? My code is below. Thanks in advance! I left out parts of the code that import some images and html as I don't believe they are part of the problem, but I can provide if necessary.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlretrieve
import os
import sys
import zipfile
import tempfile
import StringIO

def index(req):

    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    # Open StringIO to grab in-memory ZIP contents
    s = StringIO.StringIO()
    fileList = os.listdir('/tmp/images')
    fileList = ['/tmp/images/'+filename for filename in fileList]
    # The zip compressor
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")
    for file in fileList:
        archive.write(file, os.path.basename(file)) 
    zip.close()
    archive.close()
    wrapper = FileWrapper(temp)
    #Get zip file, set as attachment, get file size, set mime type
    resp = HttpResponse(wrapper, mimetype = "application/octet-stream")
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.ZIP"'
    resp['Content-Length'] = temp.tell()
    temp.seek(0)
    return resp
```

Image added to show webpage that shows when temp.seek(0) is added to moved to beginning.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try without quotes:

```
resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.ZIP'
```

I have done this before, always without quotes. Also, [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment) point that:

> To tell the browser to treat the response as a file attachment, use the content_type argument and set the Content-Disposition header.

You can try changing `mimetype` with `content_type` like this:

```
resp = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type="application/octet-stream")
```

**UPDATE:** This answer [File downloaded always blank in Python, Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703511/file-downloaded-always-blank-in-python-django/16703686#16703686) shows a code that worked. You can test it out of the box in some view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. I had double quotes around it because I saw online a few places that some browsers won't recognize it if there aren't double quotes around the file name. But with or without the quotes, it's not working. Thanks though!

Comment: Actually, in the docs, there are quotes. Did you read about `content_type`? I think that might be another problem. I was able to get it working once with some minimal code, I'll share it to you to see if it works in your box. Updated my answer

Comment: I've tried all the different content types such as application/zip, application/octet-stream, and application/x-zip-compressed and none of them yielded any different results.

Comment: Your code from the answer works, however, I can't get mine to work based off that answer. I tried moving the temp.seek(0) to the beginning and the browser shows just brings up a webpage and doesn't download anything. I added a screen shot to my main answer if it's helpful at all.

Comment: Since tell just say the current position in the file, maybe you can  try without `Content-Length`, it doesn't seems like this is the problem but is just an idea. Also, try it from another browser just in case. This should be a simple fix :( don't understand why is giving us so much trouble :(

Comment: I tried different browsers and removed the content-length and I'm still getting the same problem.